# Android Q Beta - ContentValue is empty when created from parcel

Tags: android, android-10.0

Android Build: `QPP5.190530.015`

Emulator: `Pixel 2`

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", true);
map.put("key2", "String");
map.put("key3", 3);

Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeMap(map);
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
ContentValues contentValues = ContentValues.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
```

expected result:

`contentValues would contain the data of the given map.`

actual result :

`contentValues is empty`

Comment: You are putting a `Map` into the `Parcel`, so read a `Map` out of the `Parcel`. Or, if you want to read a `ContentValues` of the `Parcel`, put a `ContentValues` into the `Parcel`. Do not assume that `Parcel` is going to convert types for you.

Comment: Does it work on the previous version of android ?

Comment: The same code work on other versions of Android except for Android Q. @CommonsWare

Comment: So? You relied on undocumented behavior. Now it does not behave that way anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### I am also facing the same issue in createFromParcel with hashmap in Android Q ,solved it by by iteration through hashmap and casting the value to its respective type.

```
  private ContentValues getContentValuesFromHashMapValues(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                String key = entry.getKey();

                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Integer) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Long) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Short) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Short) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Float) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Double) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Byte) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Byte) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                    contentValues.put(key, (Boolean) value);
                } else if (value instanceof String) {
                    contentValues.put(key, ((value == null) ? "" : (String) value));
                }
            }

            return contentValues;
        }
```